# Is it a good practice to re-create a Topic Client before sending a message to Azure Topic

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, brokeredmessage

I am using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, Version=2.0.0.0 assembly to connect to Azure Topics. The code is below

```
public void SendMessage(Message brokeredMessage) 
{
    var topicClient = new TopicClient(_configuration.ConnectionString, topicName, _defaultRetryPolicy);
    await topicClient.SendAsync(brokeredMessage);
    await topicClient.CloseAsync();
}
```

I was wondering whether it's a good practice to create the Topic Client every time I need to send a message to the topic, or should I create the Topic Client on application startup and keep using the same client every time I need to send a message?

Are there any performance or scalability issues that I need to consider?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [`Azure Service Bus Best Practices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements#reusing-factories-and-clients) post:

> ### Reusing factories and clients
>
> Service Bus client objects, such as QueueClient or MessageSender, are
>   created through a MessagingFactory object, which also provides
>   internal management of connections. You should not close messaging
>   factories or queue, topic, and subscription clients after you send a
>   message, and then re-create them when you send the next message.
>   Closing a messaging factory deletes the connection to the Service Bus
>   service, and a new connection is established when recreating the
>   factory. **Establishing a connection is an expensive operation that you
>   can avoid by re-using the same factory and client objects for multiple
>   operations.** You can safely use the QueueClient object for sending
>   messages from concurrent asynchronous operations and multiple threads.

Based on this, you should be reusing the `Topic Client` object.